# Trying to move the submit button to the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do you move the move the button to the bottom of the page? I tried and its not working. I have tried margin-bottom: 0px; but the button still not move the bottom

```
 <form tag="Create Logon">
    <div id="layer">
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        Fistname *:
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <input type="firstname" name="firstname" style="width: 300px; font-size: 14pt; margin-left: 40px;" />
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <input type="Username" name="username" style="width: 300px; font-size: 16pt; margin-left: 40px;" />
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        Password *:
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <input type="password" name="password" style="width: 300px; font-size: 16pt; margin-left: 40px;" />
    </div>
    <p>Note: Please make sure your details are correct before submitting form and that all fields marked with * are completed!</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            alert("Thank you for registering with GreenB!");
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: `0px` is incorrect; it should be just `0` (although this is not the source of your problem).

Comment: you can't close a form tag with </div>

Answer (score 3):

Use absolute positioning:

```
button {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vnLseeq2/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
button {position: absolute; bottom: 0}
```